# DBUpdate exception "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Actually, I need to update `FName` and `LName` for Contact if the entity already exists. it's checking by `Email` (unique property), all-time I get exception :

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred
> while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.  --->
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert a
> duplicate key row in object 'dbo.CONTACTS' with unique index 'EMAIL'.
> The duplicate key value is (string). The statement has been
> terminated.

My `ContactController`'s POST method:
`code`

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<Contact>> PostContact(Contact contact)
    {           
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }            
             _context.Contacts.Update(contact);                
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return CreatedAtAction("GetContact", new { id = contact.Id }, contact);                       
    }
```

That Update Method in Repository:

```
    public Contact Update(Contact entity)
    {
        var entityToUpdate =  Context.Contacts.Find(entity.Email);

        if (entityToUpdate == null)
        {
            Context.Contacts.Add(entityToUpdate);
        }

        return _mapper.Map(entity, entityToUpdate);
    }
```

I'm also try this:

```
        public void Update(Contact updatedContact)
    {
        Contact currentContact = Context.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == updatedContact.Email);
        if (currentContact == null)
            Context.Contacts.Add(updatedContact);
        else
        {

            currentContact.FirstName = updatedContact.FirstName;
            currentContact.LastName = updatedContact.LastName;
            currentContact.Email = updatedContact.Email;
            Context.Contacts.Update(currentContact);
        }
        //Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

`Contact` model:

```
 public class Contact{
    
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }      
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public int? AccountId { get; set; }
        public Account Account { get; set; }}//[Thants exception][1]
```

[Thats exception][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGklv.jpg

Comment: Try replacing this line `var entityToUpdate =  Context.Contacts.Find(entity.Email);` with 
`var entityToUpdate  = Context.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == entity.Email);` in `Update` method mentioned initially

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

```
public void Update(Contact updatedContact)
{
    Contact currentContact = Context.Contacts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email == updatedContact.Email);
    if (currentContact == null)
        Context.Contacts.Add(updatedContact);
    else
    {
        currentContact.FirstName = updatedContact.FirstName;
        currentContact.LastName = updatedContact.LastName;
    }
}
```

If e-Mail is a unique constraint then use `SingleOrDefault` rather than `FirstOrDefault`. This will at least alert you if for any reason multiple unexpected rows are found. Where there are possible multiple rows, `FirstOrDefault` should always be used with an `OrderBy*` variant.

`Update` is not necessary when working with tracked entities. When we load the applicable one, we copy across the values we allow to change, and when `SaveChanges` gets called, an UPDATE SQL statement will be generated for any fields that actually changed, *if* any of them change. We don't update the "Email" value as that is the "key" for this operation.

If this still doesn't work then the next thing to check would be how the "Context" reference is being initialized. One possible issue would be if "Context" was somehow resolving to a new DbContext instance with each access such as:

```
private YourAppDbContext Context
{
    get { return new YourAppDbContext(); }
    // or something like:
    // get { return Container.Resolve<YourAppDbContext>(); }
    // where an IoC container reference is passed in and resolves the DbContext as Transient.
}
```

Something like that would be very bad as each reference to Context would be issued a  new DbContext instance which was unaware of references loaded. Ideally the DbContext  lifetime should be managed by a container and injected:

```
public class Repository
{
     private YourAppDbContext Context { get; set; }

     public Repository(YourAppDbContext context)
     {
          Context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
     }
    
     // ...
}
```